# cat specific line range from /etc/hosts to dialog box

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu, dialog

I like to list, for example all Ethernet switches from /etc/hosts and show them inside dialog box. After that I would like to connect selected switch from the list.

The list should be listed between specific comment lines like:

/etc/hosts:

```
... 
# ETHERNET SWITCHES
192.168.0.2 SW1
192.168.0.3 SW2
192.168.0.4 SW3
# END SWITCHES
...
```

And how to connect variable $HOST with listed Switch name to do ssh connection to it IP from /etc/hosts?
It's possible something like that?

Dialog Box Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIALOG_CANCEL=1
DIALOG_ESC=255
HEIGHT=0
WIDTH=0
HOST=`cat /scripts/dialog.out`
IP=`grep '$HOST' /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}'`

display_result() {
dialog --title "$1" \
--no-collapse \
--msgbox "$result" 0 0
}
while true; do
 exec 3>&1
 selection=$(dialog \
--backtitle "" \
--title "MENU" \
--clear \
--cancel-label "EXIT" \
--menu "SELECT OPTION:" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 6 \
"1" "SW1" \
"2" "SW2" \
"3" "SW3" \
2>&1>/scripts/dialog.out 1>&3)
exit_status=$?
exec 3>&-
case $exit_status in
$DIALOG_CANCEL)
  clear
  exit
  ;;
$DIALOG_ESC)
  clear
  echo "Program aborted." >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
case $selection in
0 )
  clear
  echo "Program terminated."
  ;;
1 )
  ssh admin@$IP
  ;;
 esac
done
```

Comment: Split the problem domain into little parts. The first part might be "Extract a set of lines from a file delimited by markers". You'll find matches to questions like that here on U&L. You can then work out how to present that list in a `dialog` selection box. You can then work out how to achieve your connection of host to switch. Don't try and solve the whole requirement in one sitting - you seem to have too many unknowns. (This is intended as constructive criticism, not a refusal to help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scripting the `--menu` with [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html), the first column in the menu is a *tag*, which you can choose whether to display or not.  When the menu is OK'd, `dialog` writes those tags to its output (normally to the standard error, but the `--stdout` option helps).

If you make the IP-address a tag, you can get the addresses directly from running `dialog`.

In the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html), this optional feature is described here:

```
   --no-items
          Some  widgets  (checklist, inputmenu, radiolist, menu) display a
          list with two columns (a "tag" and "item", i.e., "description").
          This  option  tells  dialog  to  read shorter rows, omitting the
          "item" part of the list.  This is occasionally useful, e.g.,  if
          the tags provide enough information.

          See  also --no-tags.  If both options are given, this one is ig-
          nored.
```

and

```
   --no-tags
          Some  widgets  (checklist, inputmenu, radiolist, menu) display a
          list with two columns (a "tag" and "description").  The  tag  is
          useful  for scripting, but may not help the user.  The --no-tags
          option (from Xdialog) may be used to suppress the column of tags
          from  the  display.  Unlike the --no-items option, this does not
          affect the data which is read from the script.

          Xdialog does not  display  the  tag  column  for  the  analogous
          buildlist and treeview widgets; dialog does the same.

          Normally  dialog  allows  you  to quickly move to entries on the
          displayed list, by matching a  single  character  to  the  first
          character  of the tag.  When the --no-tags option is given, dia-
          log matches against the first character of the description.   In
          either case, the matchable character is highlighted.
```

You can select the lines from `/etc/hosts` in various ways, e.g., using `sed`:

```
sed -e '1,/# ETHERNET SWITCHES/d' -e '/# END SWITCHES/,9999d' /etc/hosts
```

and you could redirect that into your command-line to `dialog` by putting it in `$(` and `)`.

By combining your shortcut 1,2,3 with the SW1,SW2,SW3 in the *description* and using the `--no-tags` option, you can keep the IP-address and description associated.

The example you have in mind might be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/etc/hosts
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r addr line; do # process file by file
  let i=$i+1
  W+=($addr "$i $line")
done < <( sed -e '1,/# ETHERNET SWITCHES/d' -e '/# END SWITCHES/,9999d' $INPUT )
FILE=$(dialog --stdout --no-tags --title "List of Switches in /etc/hosts file" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" ) # show dialog and store output
clear
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then # Exit with OK
  ssh $FILE
fi
```

Comment: Yesss,
That's work perfect! Thanks for assist.